# Error in pglm estimation

Tags: r, estimation

I have tried to perform a FE Poisson regression in R using the command `pglm` from the `pglm` package (equivalent to `xtpoisson` for Stata users). Unfortunately, I get an error message that I don't understand. 
I would really appreciate if you can point out what I am doing wrong.

Data looks like the following:

```
structure(list(y = c(58L, 85L, 46L, 72L, 55L, 61L, 10L, 13L, 
5L, 11L, 10L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 25L, 52L, 50L, 29L, 57L, 
2L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 138L, 160L, 141L, 194L, 
96L, 127L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 
43L, 32L, 52L, 46L, 45L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 197L, 335L, 181L, 224L, 366L, 143L, 14L, 16L, 33L, 33L, 28L, 
16L, 5L, 5L, 15L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 21L, 76L, 76L, 33L, 46L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 66L, 100L, 114L, 106L, 74L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 38L, 41L, 69L, 
62L, 42L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 74L, 
80L, 75L, 38L, 24L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 818L, 
622L, 619L, 600L, 484L, 564L, 52L, 25L, 22L, 28L, 20L, 25L, 19L, 
11L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 19L, 11L, 43L, 42L, 95L, 7L, 11L, 
3L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 15L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 31L, 37L, 50L, 37L, 
43L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 335L, 411L, 404L, 
328L, 354L, 287L, 44L, 18L, 30L, 34L, 28L, 23L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 
11L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
0L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 108L, 74L, 85L, 107L, 52L, 51L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 186L, 228L, 163L, 185L, 156L, 136L, 19L, 20L, 
12L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 320L, 311L, 177L, 172L, 156L, 
180L, 53L, 28L, 17L, 21L, 13L, 28L, 27L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 
18L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), i = c(2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 7832, 7832, 7832, 7832, 7832, 7832, 15662, 15662, 
15662, 15662, 15662, 15662, 23492, 23492, 23492, 23492, 23492, 
23492, 31322, 31322, 31322, 31322, 31322, 31322, 39152, 39152, 
39152, 39152, 39152, 39152, 46982, 46982, 46982, 46982, 46982, 
46982, 54812, 54812, 54812, 54812, 54812, 54812, 62642, 62642, 
62642, 62642, 62642, 62642, 70472, 70472, 70472, 70472, 70472, 
70472, 78302, 78302, 78302, 78302, 78302, 78302, 86132, 86132, 
86132, 86132, 86132, 86132, 93962, 93962, 93962, 93962, 93962, 
93962, 101792, 101792, 101792, 101792, 101792, 101792, 109622, 
109622, 109622, 109622, 109622, 109622, 117452, 117452, 117452, 
117452, 117452, 117452, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7833, 7833, 7833, 7833, 
7833, 7833, 15663, 15663, 15663, 15663, 15663, 15663, 23493, 
23493, 23493, 23493, 23493, 23493, 31323, 31323, 31323, 31323, 
31323, 31323, 39153, 39153, 39153, 39153, 39153, 39153, 46983, 
46983, 46983, 46983, 46983, 46983, 54813, 54813, 54813, 54813, 
54813, 54813, 62643, 62643, 62643, 62643, 62643, 62643, 70473, 
70473, 70473, 70473, 70473, 70473, 78303, 78303, 78303, 78303, 
78303, 78303, 86133, 86133, 86133, 86133, 86133, 86133, 93963, 
93963, 93963, 93963, 93963, 93963, 101793, 101793, 101793, 101793, 
101793, 101793, 109623, 109623, 109623, 109623, 109623, 109623, 
117453, 117453, 117453, 117453, 117453, 117453, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 7834, 7834, 7834, 7834, 7834, 7834, 15664, 15664, 15664, 15664, 
15664, 15664, 23494, 23494, 23494, 23494, 23494, 23494, 31324, 
31324, 31324, 31324, 31324, 31324, 39154, 39154, 39154, 39154, 
39154, 39154, 46984, 46984, 46984, 46984, 46984, 46984, 54814, 
54814, 54814, 54814, 54814, 54814, 62644, 62644, 62644, 62644, 
62644, 62644, 70474, 70474, 70474, 70474, 70474, 70474, 78304, 
78304, 78304, 78304, 78304, 78304, 86134, 86134, 86134, 86134, 
86134, 86134, 93964, 93964, 93964, 93964, 93964, 93964, 101794, 
101794, 101794, 101794, 101794, 101794, 109624, 109624, 109624, 
109624, 109624, 109624, 117454, 117454, 117454, 117454, 117454, 
117454, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7835, 7835, 7835, 7835, 7835, 7835, 
15665, 15665, 15665, 15665, 15665, 15665, 23495, 23495, 23495, 
23495, 23495, 23495, 31325, 31325, 31325, 31325, 31325, 31325, 
39155, 39155, 39155, 39155, 39155, 39155, 46985, 46985, 46985, 
46985, 46985, 46985, 54815, 54815, 54815, 54815, 54815, 54815, 
62645, 62645, 62645, 62645, 62645, 62645, 70475, 70475, 70475, 
70475, 70475, 70475, 78305, 78305, 78305, 78305, 78305, 78305, 
86135, 86135, 86135, 86135, 86135, 86135, 93965, 93965, 93965, 
93965, 93965, 93965, 101795, 101795, 101795, 101795, 101795, 
101795, 109625, 109625, 109625, 109625, 109625, 109625, 117455, 
117455, 117455, 117455, 117455, 117455, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7836, 
7836, 7836, 7836, 7836, 7836, 15666, 15666, 15666, 15666, 15666, 
15666, 23496, 23496, 23496, 23496, 23496, 23496, 31326, 31326, 
31326, 31326, 31326, 31326, 39156, 39156, 39156, 39156, 39156, 
39156, 46986, 46986, 46986, 46986, 46986, 46986, 54816, 54816, 
54816, 54816, 54816, 54816, 62646, 62646, 62646, 62646, 62646, 
62646, 70476, 70476, 70476, 70476, 70476, 70476, 78306, 78306, 
78306, 78306, 78306, 78306, 86136, 86136, 86136, 86136, 86136, 
86136, 93966, 93966, 93966, 93966, 93966, 93966, 101796, 101796, 
101796, 101796, 101796, 101796, 109626, 109626, 109626, 109626, 
109626, 109626, 117456, 117456, 117456, 117456, 117456, 117456, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7837, 7837, 7837, 7837, 7837, 7837, 15667, 
15667, 15667, 15667, 15667, 15667, 23497, 23497, 23497, 23497, 
23497, 23497, 31327, 31327, 31327, 31327, 31327, 31327, 39157, 
39157, 39157, 39157, 39157, 39157, 46987, 46987, 46987, 46987, 
46987, 46987, 54817, 54817, 54817, 54817, 54817, 54817, 62647, 
62647, 62647, 62647, 62647, 62647, 70477, 70477, 70477, 70477, 
70477, 70477, 78307, 78307, 78307, 78307, 78307, 78307, 86137, 
86137, 86137, 86137, 86137, 86137, 93967, 93967, 93967, 93967, 
93967, 93967, 101797, 101797, 101797, 101797, 101797, 101797, 
109627, 109627, 109627, 109627, 109627, 109627, 117457, 117457, 
117457, 117457, 117457, 117457, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7839, 7839, 
7839, 7839, 7839, 7839, 15669, 15669, 15669, 15669, 15669, 15669, 
23499, 23499, 23499, 23499, 23499, 23499, 31329, 31329, 31329, 
31329, 31329, 31329, 39159, 39159, 39159, 39159, 39159, 39159, 
46989, 46989, 46989, 46989, 46989, 46989, 54819, 54819, 54819, 
54819, 54819, 54819, 62649, 62649, 62649, 62649, 62649, 62649, 
70479, 70479, 70479, 70479, 70479, 70479, 78309, 78309, 78309, 
78309, 78309, 78309, 86139, 86139, 86139, 86139, 86139, 86139, 
93969, 93969, 93969, 93969, 93969, 93969, 101799, 101799, 101799, 
101799, 101799, 101799, 109629, 109629, 109629, 109629, 109629, 
109629, 117459, 117459, 117459, 117459, 117459, 117459, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 7840, 7840, 7840, 7840, 7840, 7840, 15670, 15670, 
15670, 15670, 15670, 15670, 23500, 23500, 23500, 23500, 23500, 
23500, 31330, 31330, 31330, 31330, 31330, 31330, 39160, 39160, 
39160, 39160, 39160, 39160, 46990, 46990, 46990, 46990, 46990, 
46990, 54820, 54820, 54820, 54820, 54820, 54820, 62650, 62650, 
62650, 62650, 62650, 62650, 70480, 70480, 70480, 70480, 70480, 
70480, 78310, 78310, 78310, 78310, 78310, 78310, 86140, 86140, 
86140, 86140, 86140, 86140, 93970, 93970, 93970, 93970, 93970, 
93970, 101800, 101800, 101800, 101800, 101800, 101800, 109630, 
109630, 109630, 109630, 109630, 109630, 117460, 117460, 117460, 
117460, 117460, 117460, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 7842, 7842, 7842, 
7842, 7842, 7842, 15672, 15672, 15672, 15672, 15672, 15672, 23502, 
23502, 23502, 23502, 23502, 23502, 31332, 31332, 31332, 31332, 
31332, 31332, 39162, 39162, 39162, 39162, 39162, 39162, 46992, 
46992, 46992, 46992, 46992, 46992, 54822, 54822, 54822, 54822, 
54822, 54822, 62652, 62652, 62652, 62652, 62652, 62652, 70482, 
70482, 70482, 70482, 70482, 70482, 78312, 78312, 78312, 78312, 
78312, 78312, 86142, 86142, 86142, 86142, 86142, 86142, 93972, 
93972, 93972, 93972, 93972, 93972, 101802, 101802, 101802, 101802, 
101802, 101802, 109632, 109632, 109632, 109632, 109632, 109632, 
117462, 117462, 117462, 117462, 117462, 117462, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 7843, 7843, 7843, 7843, 7843, 7843, 15673, 15673, 15673, 
15673, 15673, 15673, 23503, 23503, 23503, 23503, 23503, 23503, 
31333, 31333, 31333, 31333, 31333, 31333, 39163, 39163, 39163, 
39163, 39163, 39163, 46993, 46993, 46993, 46993, 46993, 46993, 
54823, 54823, 54823, 54823, 54823, 54823, 62653, 62653, 62653, 
62653, 62653, 62653, 70483, 70483, 70483, 70483, 70483, 70483, 
78313, 78313, 78313, 78313, 78313, 78313, 86143, 86143, 86143, 
86143, 86143, 86143, 93973, 93973, 93973, 93973, 93973, 93973, 
101803, 101803, 101803, 101803, 101803, 101803, 109633, 109633, 
109633, 109633, 109633, 109633, 117463, 117463, 117463, 117463, 
117463, 117463, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 7847, 7847, 7847, 7847, 
7847, 7847, 15677, 15677, 15677, 15677, 15677, 15677, 23507, 
23507, 23507, 23507, 23507, 23507, 31337, 31337, 31337, 31337, 
31337, 31337, 39167, 39167, 39167, 39167, 39167, 39167, 46997, 
46997, 46997, 46997, 46997, 46997, 54827, 54827, 54827, 54827, 
54827, 54827, 62657, 62657, 62657, 62657, 62657, 62657, 70487, 
70487, 70487, 70487, 70487, 70487, 78317, 78317, 78317, 78317, 
78317, 78317, 86147, 86147, 86147, 86147, 86147, 86147, 93977, 
93977, 93977, 93977, 93977, 93977, 101807, 101807, 101807, 101807, 
101807, 101807, 109637, 109637, 109637, 109637, 109637, 109637, 
117467, 117467, 117467, 117467, 117467, 117467, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 7848, 7848, 7848, 7848, 7848, 7848, 15678, 15678, 15678, 
15678, 15678, 15678, 23508, 23508, 23508, 23508, 23508, 23508, 
31338, 31338, 31338, 31338, 31338, 31338, 39168, 39168, 39168, 
39168, 39168, 39168, 46998, 46998, 46998, 46998, 46998, 46998, 
54828, 54828, 54828, 54828, 54828, 54828, 62658, 62658, 62658, 
62658, 62658, 62658, 70488, 70488, 70488, 70488, 70488, 70488, 
78318, 78318, 78318, 78318, 78318, 78318, 86148, 86148, 86148, 
86148, 86148, 86148, 93978, 93978, 93978, 93978, 93978, 93978, 
101808, 101808, 101808, 101808, 101808, 101808, 109638, 109638, 
109638, 109638, 109638, 109638, 117468, 117468, 117468, 117468, 
117468, 117468, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 7851, 7851, 7851, 7851, 
7851, 7851, 15681, 15681, 15681, 15681, 15681, 15681, 23511, 
23511, 23511, 23511, 23511, 23511, 31341, 31341, 31341, 31341, 
31341, 31341, 39171, 39171, 39171, 39171, 39171, 39171, 47001, 
47001, 47001, 47001, 47001, 47001, 54831, 54831, 54831, 54831, 
54831, 54831, 62661, 62661, 62661, 62661, 62661, 62661, 70491, 
70491, 70491, 70491, 70491, 70491, 78321, 78321, 78321, 78321, 
78321, 78321, 86151, 86151, 86151, 86151, 86151, 86151, 93981, 
93981, 93981, 93981, 93981, 93981, 101811, 101811, 101811, 101811, 
101811, 101811, 109641, 109641, 109641, 109641, 109641, 109641, 
117471, 117471, 117471, 117471, 117471, 117471, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 7852, 7852, 7852, 7852, 7852, 7852, 15682, 15682, 15682, 
15682, 15682, 15682, 23512, 23512, 23512, 23512, 23512, 23512, 
31342, 31342, 31342, 31342, 31342, 31342, 39172, 39172, 39172, 
39172, 39172, 39172, 47002, 47002, 47002, 47002, 47002, 47002, 
54832, 54832, 54832, 54832, 54832, 54832, 62662, 62662, 62662, 
62662, 62662, 62662, 70492, 70492, 70492, 70492, 70492, 70492, 
78322, 78322, 78322, 78322, 78322, 78322, 86152, 86152, 86152, 
86152, 86152, 86152, 93982, 93982, 93982, 93982, 93982, 93982, 
101812, 101812, 101812, 101812, 101812, 101812, 109642, 109642, 
109642, 109642, 109642, 109642, 117472, 117472, 117472, 117472, 
117472, 117472, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 7856, 7856, 7856, 7856, 
7856, 7856, 15686, 15686, 15686, 15686, 15686, 15686, 23516, 
23516, 23516, 23516, 23516, 23516, 31346, 31346, 31346, 31346, 
31346, 31346, 39176, 39176, 39176, 39176, 39176, 39176, 47006, 
47006, 47006, 47006, 47006, 47006, 54836, 54836, 54836, 54836, 
54836, 54836, 62666, 62666, 62666, 62666, 62666, 62666, 70496, 
70496, 70496, 70496, 70496, 70496, 78326, 78326, 78326, 78326, 
78326, 78326, 86156, 86156, 86156, 86156, 86156, 86156, 93986, 
93986, 93986, 93986, 93986, 93986, 101816, 101816, 101816, 101816, 
101816, 101816, 109646, 109646, 109646, 109646, 109646, 109646, 
117476, 117476, 117476, 117476, 117476, 117476, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 7857, 7857, 7857, 7857, 7857, 7857, 15687, 15687, 15687, 
15687, 15687, 15687, 23517, 23517, 23517, 23517, 23517, 23517, 
31347, 31347, 31347, 31347, 31347, 31347, 39177, 39177, 39177, 
39177, 39177, 39177, 47007, 47007, 47007, 47007, 47007, 47007, 
54837, 54837, 54837, 54837, 54837, 54837, 62667, 62667, 62667, 
62667, 62667, 62667, 70497, 70497, 70497, 70497, 70497, 70497
), x = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("y", 
"i", "x"), class = "data.frame")
```

My code is :

```
res1 <- pglm(y ~  x , family = poisson, data = reg_data,
         effect = "individual", model="within", index = "i")
```

The error message is the following:

> Error in maxNRCompute(fn = function (theta, fnOrig, gradOrig = NULL, hessOrig = NULL,  : length of gradient (6) not equal to the no. of parameters (1)"

My understanding of the problem is that it does not depend on the covariate variable (i.e. I still get the error if I replace the covariate with another one). It looks like nothing is wrong with the data itself, since the regression runs just fine if I run an OLS (i.e. using `lm` instead of `pglm`).

Comment: is that all of your data? we ideally need a **reproducible** example in order to trouble-shoot ... see [mcve], https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks a lot for your feedback. I have reproduced a minimal dataset to visualise my error, based on the link that you sent me. Hopefully this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what's going wrong, and I don't know enough about econometric methods to know what the "within" specification really means, but I can show you that this data set contains barely any information, which makes it unsurprising that you can't fit a model successfully:

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(reg_data,aes(x,y,colour=factor(i)))+
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.01))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

This shows that almost all of the data are at x=0, with only a few points at x=1. Digging a little deeper:

Cross-tabulate the distribution of x values within each `i`:

```
tt <- with(dd,table(x,i))
```

Summarise these:

```
table(apply(tt,2,paste,collapse="."))
## 5.1 6.0 
##   3 247
```

This means that of your 250 clusters of six points each, 247 of them have *only* x=0 values. 3 of them have 5 points at x=0 and 1 point at x=1. It's not surprising to me that any method that tries to do anything with the clusters fails ...

If I specify `method="pooling"` then I get an answer which is identical (identical coefficients, anyway) to the results of `glm(y~x,data=reg_data,family=poisson)` ...

Maybe your real data set isn't quite this extreme?